# in DXL, how to get the handle of a module that I don't open myself in the DXL script

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a DXL script that open (read or edit) modules and put them in a skip list (so that I could close them at the end)

The skip list store the module handle of each module read or edit :

```
if (MODIF_OTHER_MODULES)
{
modSrc = edit(modSrc_Name, false)
} else 
{
modSrc = read(modSrc_Name, false) 
}
put(skp_openmodule, modSrc, modSrc)
```

But sometimes modules are already open outside my DXL script so following check is KO :

```
mvSource = sourceVersion lr 
modSrc_data = data mvSource 
modSrc_Name = fullName(source lr)

if (null modSrc_data)
"read/edit modSrc_Name module and add module in the skip list" : OK DONE
else
"the module is already open but maybe I don't open it myself"
"so I WANT TO CHECK if module is already in the skiplist and ADD module of modSrc_data in the precedent skip list if it isn't " : I DONT KNOW HOW !
```

"

Is there a way to get module of modSrc_data so that it could be added in skp_openmodule if it is not already present in the list ?

I don't want to read/edit it again because I don't know in which mode it was open previously and I would prefer to avoid it because I will do it for each objet and each link !

also it would be great if I could also retrieve the information about how the module was open (read or edit)

I tried :
module (modSrc_data)
and
module(modSrc_Name)
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is due to the excerpt you posted, but you should always turn off the autodeclare option and ensure that you always use the correct types for your variables by either checking the DXL manual or by using alternative sources like the "undocumented perms list" . `data` performed on a `ModuleVersion` returns type `Module`. So you already have what you need.  An alternative would be the perm `bool open(ModName_ modRef)`. And note that the perm `module` does not return a `Module`, but a `ModName_`.
Also, in addition to `bool isRead(Module m)`, `bool isEdit(Module m)` and `bool isShare(Module m)`(!!) when you really want to close modules that have been opened previously, you might want to check `bool unsaved(Module m)`

```
ModuleVersion mvSource = sourceVersion lr 
Module modSrc_data = data mvSource 
string modSrc_Name = fullName(source lr)

if (null modSrc_data)
    print "read/edit modSrc_Name module and add module in the skip list" 
else
{
    print "the module is already open but maybe I don't open it myself"
    if isRead (modSrc_data) then print " - read"
    if isEdit (modSrc_data) then print " - edit"
    if isShare (modSrc_data) then print " - shared mode"
    if unsaved (modSrc_data) then print " - do not silently close me, otherwise the user might be infuriated"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, modSrc_data was the first thing I tried but I did a mistake because it wasn't working. now it is. great ! thanks also for the boolean function.

modSrc_data was correclty declared as module, yes.
what is difference between module and modename_ for my culture ?

Comment: `ModName_` is like a reference to a module. It's used e.g. when you need some information about a module, but don't actually need or want to open it. `bool exists(ModName_ modRef)` is a good example for usage. `Module` is a handle to a module that has actually been opened, that you can use e.g. to iterate over all Objects inside it

Comment: but in real how can I use it ? for instance I have a module TOTO that is open. let's assume that later in the code I want to check if TOTO is open or not.
function is bool open(ModName_ modRef)
how to convert TOTO that is a module to the type ModName_ ? so that I could use TOTO in "open" function ?

Comment: The following perms return a ModName_: 
ModName_ getTargetModule (Linkset)
ModName_ target (Link)
ModName_ module (ModuleVersion)
ModName_ source (LinkRef)
ModName_ source (ExternalLink)
ModName_ module (string name)
ModName_ source (Link)
ModName_ getModuleByRifID (Folder, string)
ModName_ getModuleByRifID (Folder, string)
ModName_ getModuleByRifID (Project, string)
ModName_ getModuleByRifID (Project, string)
ModName_ module (Module module)
So, this is possible:
`Item i
for i in current Folder do {
print fullName i"-"
ModName_ mn = module(fullName i)
print open (mn) "\n"
}`